# Errors with smooth scrolling and active class

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

hey someone did have problems with smooth scrolling and dynamic active classes? it shows me problems on this website: 
https://dkapexhiu.github.io/brooklyn-outdoor-film-festival/
and the script is here: 
https://github.com/dkapexhiu/brooklyn-outdoor-film-festival/blob/master/js/script.js
please navigate to some sections to see some errors on scrolling

Answer (score 0):

For Scrolling smooth add this

```
$('classname').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var hlink = $(this).attr("href");
    $("body,html").animate({
    scrollTop: $(hlink).offset().top
    },500);
});
```